# Get the email address from the identity name

Tags: magento2, email

I have a special form that when filled needs to send a notification mail to the admin. I used a system.xml to have it selected and stored in the database :

```xml
    <field id="identity" translate="label" type="select" sortOrder="20" showInDefault="1" showInWebsite="1" showInStore="1" canRestore="1">
        <label>Sender</label>
        <source_model>Magento\Config\Model\Config\Source\Email\Identity</source_model>
    </field>
```

Then I can retrieve it like that :

```php
    $this->scopeConfig->getValue(
            'mysection/mygroup/identity',
            \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
        )
```

And I get e.g. the string "Sales" that correspond to the entry in vendor/magento/module-email/etc/config.xml :

```xml
    <trans_email>
        ...
        <ident_sales>
            <email>sales@example.com</email>
            <name>Sales</name>
        </ident_sales>
        ...
    </trans_email>
```

Is there a way to easily retrieve the email corresponding to the name ?

*In the example, I told "Sales" but it can be changed as there is a dropdown so I need to be able to map the name to the email rather that hardcode the sales email address.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```php
...
use Magento\Framework\Mail\Template\SenderResolverInterface $senderResolver
...

$identity = $this->senderResolver->resolve($this->scopeConfig->getValue(
    'sgecomoutofstock/outofstocksubscription/identity',
    \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE
));

...
```

The variable `$identity` will contain an array with the name and the email.